# How to create a Window's 10 like Progress bar in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows, progress-bar

I am looking for how-to information on how to create a progress bar that looks like a Windows 10 version, especially when the task is not done, there is a glowing markee on the "done" area of the progress bar.

Something like during a "Windows Explorer" search... until the search is done you'll see the progress bar is glowing.

I tried googling around, and all sites are explaining just the simple and straightforward progressbar.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the below answers... to emphasize what i'm looking for, take a look at the below picture.... This is a sanpshot from a simple copy dialog. you can see while the copy is in progress, a glowing effect on the progress bar itself.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're looking for but there is an `IsIndeterminate` property on the standard `ProgressBar`, which when set to true, gives a continuous effect rather than a bar which represents a value relative to a determinate, finite maximum value.   See [MSDN Progress Bar IsIndeterminate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate(v=vs.110).aspx)